# How many integer-sided right triangles are there whose sides are combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

> How many integer-sided right triangles exist whose sides are combinations of the form $\displaystyle \binom{x}{2},\displaystyle \binom{y}{2},\displaystyle \binom{z}{2}$?

**Attempt:**

This seems like a hard question, since I can't even think of one example to this. Mathematically we have,

$$\left(\dfrac{x(x-1)}{2} \right)^2+\left (\dfrac{y(y-1)}{2} \right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{z(z-1)}{2} \right)^2\tag1$$

where we have to find all positive *integer* solutions $(x,y,z)$.

I find this hard to do. But here was my idea. Since we have $x^2(x-1)^2+y^2(y-1)^2 = z^2(z-1)^2$, we can try doing $x = y+1$. If we can prove there are infinitely many solutions to,

$$(y+1)^2y^2+y^2(y-1)^2 = z^2(z-1)^2\tag2$$

then we are done.

Comment: Well if $x = y$ then you're looking at $45$-$45$-$90$ triangles, and certainly those don't have integer side lengths

Comment: @pjs36 Good point. Still trying to find solutions to this is going to be hard I think.

Comment: Your approach seems cool - however, the only solution for $y^2(y+1)^2+y^2(y-1)^2=z^2(z-1)^2$ with $y<1,000,000$ is $(y,z)=(1,2)$ (checked with Wolfram Mathematica 10.0). Not too promising, unfortunately...

Comment: For a similar equation to write the solution turned out to be.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1054874_triangular_numbers_for_pythagorean_triples  And this is complicated and does not work.

Comment: I might mention that this is an unsolved problem: https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjos5-50JDLAhXCkJQKHQWaBckQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fq.math.ca%2FScanned%2F17-2%2Fballew.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEJJl_aJkyH3zZYBACg_G6J6Unyug&sig2=hjJZTOFgjmcD3-GD98RTPQ&bvm=bv.114733917,d.dGo&cad=rjt

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start the other way around, by the formula to generate all [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Comment: Did this hint enable you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solving $(1)$ for $z$, we have,

$$z = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1\pm4w}}{2}\tag3$$

where,

$$w^2 = (x^2-x)^2+(y^2-y)^2\tag4$$

It can be shown that $(4)$ has infinitely many integer solutions. (*Update*: Also proven by Sierpinski in 1961. See link given by MXYMXY, *[Pythagorean Triples and Triangular Numbers](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/17-2/ballew.pdf)* by Ballew and Weger, 1979.)

However, the problem is you still have to solve $(3)$. I found with a computer search that with $x<y<1000$, the only integers are $x,y,z = 133,\,144,\,165$, so,

$$\left(\dfrac{133(133-1)}{2} \right)^2+\left (\dfrac{144(144-1)}{2} \right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{165(165-1)}{2} \right)^2$$

**P.S.** If you're curious about *rational* solutions, then your $(1)$ and $(2)$ have infinitely many.

Comment: For $(4)$, by observing the results of a computer search, if $w,x,y = 2uv,\,u,\,u+1$, then integer solutions can be found using the _Pell equation_ $u^2-2v^2=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

For your equation, solutions include
$$(1,1,1)\quad (1,2,2)\quad (1,3,3)\quad (1,3,3)\quad
 (1,4,4)\quad (1,5,5)\quad \cdots $$
Any triple with zero or one for one of $\space x,y\space $ will work. All others would probably require a brute force search.